# Devise authentication. undefined method 'authenticate_member!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am trying to use:

```
before_filter :authenticate_member!
before_filter :authenticate_user!

current_member
current_user
```

in my controller (not at the same time, of course). None of these names could be found. I have installed Devise according to manual: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Restarting server after changing the line does not help.

Comment: didn't forget to restart server ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ugly Rails defaults! If the user model's name is `Restuser` then the calls should be:

```
before_filter :authenticate_restuser!
```

and

```
current_restuser
```

Comment: except no spaces: before_filter :authenticate_restuser!

Comment: sure. Stackoverflow didn't allow to make parts of the word bold, so I have put spaces.

Comment: I didn't realise the spaces weren't meant to be there the first time I saw this. So my cut n paste didn't work at first.

Comment: @Paul I hope you don't mind -- I made it code with bold. Check the source for how (though I'd be surprised if you didn't know)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I didn't know that plain HTML markup works on SO. Or, more precise: I know that some HTML tags aren't working here, so I stopped trying. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul Yeah, it's weird. It's normally better to use four spaces, but if you want that formatting, you have to go to HTML and be really careful to escape any HTML inside or even anything that looks like HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sure first the user and member model created with devise.

Then you check user can sign-up and sign in.

If user sign-in then you will

```
       puts current_user.inspect
```

it returns sign-in user object.....

Comment: Where to put this if no method could be called?